# apostrophe is shown as ascii on webchat control

Tags: c#, ascii, botframework, web-chat

how come the apostrophe always shows up as an ascii on the webchat control? it is properly rendered on the test page of the qnamaker. see attached codes and pictures.
this is how i add it on the qna maker knowledge base:

```
\n\n\t •Please check your computer's power cord.
```

QNAMaker Test Page:
[image]

however when i test it on the webchat control it appears like this.

[image]

using asci code instead of the apostrophe also wont fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried a different encoding? Like UTF-8?

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: i also noticed that < > also does not work.

Comment: how you are referencing the botchat.js file. ? If storing a local copy, do not copy paste the js from browser instead save it and use

Comment: im using the webchat control. im calling it on the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your bot likes the following in web client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js" </script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add the following line in the `head` to modify the charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
```

Comment: i believe this is what you use to call a direct line, not a webchat control

Comment: This is the web chat control, just not in an Iframe.  I believe you will need to use this to fix your problem.  Webchat uses Directline.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem to happen on macs, not pc. My solution was to add this into my utterance sanitizer that would replace certain characters and therefore allow the Bot to handle it as expected